# HERE Maps not loading map image on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, here-api

We are using JS HERE maps (v3.1.16) on a single page .net core website.

The map loads fine in Chrome, IE11, Edge & Firefox on desktop, and loads fine in Chrome on Android devices. However it will not load on any iPhone or iPad browsers.

We can see our custom markers, but the map image is not being returned, we are just getting a blue box.

Tried browsing the examples on the HERE Maps documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js) and this too does not load the map in Safari on iPhone. We have tried 2 iPhones and an iPad.

Is this a known issue? Is there something that we need to put in place to make it compatible?

I can provide code if required.

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet ? also try to modify the div height width if specified.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be the Content-Security-Policy set up on our site. Managed to get hold of a mac and found the error

"refused to load blob:[blob url] because it appears in neither the child-src nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy"

Adding child-src blob: to the response headers seems to resolve the issue.